# Multiple Q.all inside function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, promise, q

I want to send a list of new books to a user. So far the below code works fine. The problem is that I don't want to send a book multiple times, so I want to filter them.

Current code works fine:

```
function checkActiveBooks(books) {
  var queue = _(books).map(function(book) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    // Get all alerts on given keywords
    request('http://localhost:5000/books?l=0&q=' + book.name, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
      }

      var books = JSON.parse(body);
      if (!_.isEmpty(books)) {

        // Loop through users of current book.
        var userBooks = _(book.users).map(function(user) {

            // Save object for this user with name and deals.
            return {
              user: user,
              book: book.name,
              books: books
            }

        });

        if (_.isEmpty(userBooks)) {
           deferred.resolve(null);
         } else {
           deferred.resolve(userBooks);
         }
      } else {
        deferred.resolve(null);
      }

    });

    return deferred.promise;

  });

  return Q.all(queue);
}
```

But now I want to filter already sent books:

```
function checkActiveBooks(books) {
    var queue = _(books).map(function(book) {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        // Get all alerts on given keywords
        request('http://localhost:5000/books?l=0&q=' + book.name, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }
            var books = JSON.parse(body);
            if (!_.isEmpty(books)) {
                // Loop through users of current book.
                var userBooks = _(book.users).map(function(user) {
                    var defer = Q.defer();
                    var userBook = user.userBook.dataValues;
                    // Check per given UserBook which books are already sent to the user by mail
                    checkSentBooks(userBook).then(function(sentBooks) {
                        // Filter books which are already sent.
                        var leftBooks = _.reject(books, function(obj) {
                            return sentBooks.indexOf(obj.id) > -1;
                        });
                        // Save object for this user with name and deals.
                        var result = {
                            user: user,
                            book: book.name,
                            books: leftBooks
                        }
                        return deferred.resolve(result);
                    });
                    return Q.all(userBooks);
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(null);
                }
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        });
        return Q.all(queue);
    }
```

But above code doesn't work. It doesn't stop looping. I thought it made sense to use q.all twice, because it contains two loops. But I guess I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't stop looping"?

Comment: The only problem I see is that `checkSentBooks` might be called before all `checkActiveBooks` `request()`s are done. Is there are race condition on your server that these depend on each other?

Comment: Well it did stop looping, but I didn't return a response, my bad. But the fact that checkSentBook is asynchronous is a problem. It contains a promise as well, cause checkSentBook does a call to the database using Sequelize JS. That's the reason I had two q.all. My problem now is that the .map function doesn't wait for the checkSentBook function to return the database result, so my books object inside the array stays empty. The double q.all don't work. Check Benjamin's answer below and my responses on that answer.

Comment: I've taken the freedom to re-indent your code. As you can see, there is a missing brace somewhere. The double `Q.all` should work; try Benjamin's suggestion of promisifiying the function and rewrite your code without calling `Q.defer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acting on @Benjamins's suggestion, here is what the code would look like when `checkSentBooks` returns a promise:

```
var request = Q.nfbind(require("request")); // a promised version.
function checkActiveBooks(books) {
    return Q.all(_(books).map(function(book) {
        // a callback with multiple arguments will resolve the promise with
        // an array, so we use `spread` here
        return request('http://localhost:5000/books?l=0&q=' + book.name).spread(function(response, body) {
            var books = JSON.parse(body);
            if (_.isEmpty(books)) return null;
            return Q.all(_(book.users).map(function(user) {
                return checkSentBooks(user.userBook.dataValues).then(function(sentBooks) {
//              ^^^^^^ return a promise to the array for `Q.all`
                    return {
                        user: user,
                        book: book.name,
                        books:  _.reject(books, function(obj) {
                            return sentBooks.indexOf(obj.id) > -1;
                        })
                    };
                });
            }));
        });
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it slightly different, but it's almost the same. It works :) Thank you for your help, Bergi and Benjamin!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should always promisify at the lowest level. You're complicating things here and have multiple deferreds. Generally you should only have deferreds when converting an API to promises. Promises chain and compose so let's do that :)

```
var request = Q.nfbind(require("request")); // a promised version.
```

This can make your code in the top section become:

```
function checkActiveBooks(books) {
    return Q.all(books.map(function(book){
        return request('http://.../books?l=0&q=' + book.name)
               .get(1) // body
               .then(JSON.parse) // parse body as json
               .then(function(book){
                    if(_.isEmpty(book.users)) return null; 
                    return book.users.map(function(user){
                         return {user: user, book: book.name, books: books };
                    });
               });
    });
}
```

Which is a lot more elegant in my opinion.

Now, if we want to filter them by a predicate we can do:

```
function checkActiveBooksThatWereNotSent(books) {
      return checkActiveBooks(books).then(function(books){
          return books.filter(function(book){ 
                    return checkSentBooks(book.book); 
                 });
      });
}
```

It's worth mentioning that the Bluebird library has utility methods for all this like `Promise#filter` and `Promise#map` that'd make this code shorter.

Note that if `checkSentBook` is asynchronous you'd need to modify the code slightly:

```
function checkActiveBooksThatWereNotSent(books) {
      return checkActiveBooks(books).then(function(books){
          return Q.all(books.map(function(book){ // note the Q.all
                    return Q.all([book, checkSentBooks(book.book)]); 
                 })).then(function(results){ 
                    return results.filter(function(x){ return x[1]; })
                                  .map(function(x){ return x[0]; });
                 });
      });
}
```

Like I said, with different libraries this would look a lot nicer. Here is how the code would look like in Bluebird which is also two orders of magnitude faster and has good stack traces and detection of unhandled rejections. For fun and glory I threw in ES6 arrows and shorthand properties:

```
var request = Promise.promisify(require("request"));

var checkActiveBooks = (books) =>
    Promise.
    map(books, book => request("...&q=" + book.name).get(1)).
    map(JSON.parse).
    map(book => book.users.length ? 
        book.users.map(user => {user, books, book: book.name) : null))

var checkActiveBooksThatWereNotSent = (books) =>
     checkActiveBooks(books).filter(checkBookSent)
```

Which I find a lot nicer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Looks very neat, indeed. But the fact that ```checkSentBook``` is asynchronous is my problem. It contains a promise as well, cause ```checkSentBook``` does a call to the database using Sequelize JS. That's the reason I had two q.all. Do you have a solution for this? I have to call the ```checkSentBook``` function inside the ```book.users.map``` loop. My problem now is that the ```.map``` function doesn't wait for the ```checkSentBook``` function to return the database result, so my books object inside the array stays empty.

Comment: If I don't call the ```checkSentBook``` inside the ```book.users.map``` function I have to right a bunch more code, cause then I have to compare two large arrays with a large amount of objects. Tried that yesterday, so calling the ```checkSentBook``` inside the ```book.users.map``` loop seems to be the best and easiest solution. Only the fact that it's asynchronous, makes it complicated for me.

Comment: @ErikVandeVen very well! this is actually not very hard to deal with! I'm editing my answer assuming that `checkSentBooks` returns a promise correctly (rather than take a callback).

Comment: For fun and glory… I see :-P